# Iterating to a numpy list

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I've been looking around but I have still faced problems with understanding the error in my code. I am trying to get get_pos values listed in pos_list array of size (numstep, N, 3). The values for get_pos is clearly checking as numstep,N,3 but when I call for pos_list at the bottom, it only prints out the last value. Is there anything I've missed?

```
 def get_pos(p_list, N):
    sys_position = np.zeros([N,3])
    for i in range(N):
        sys_position[i] = p_list[i].pos
        
    return sys_position

 pos_list = np.zeros([numstep, N, 3])

 for num in range(numstep):
     # Update particle position
     update_pos(p_list, dt, N)
        
     # Update force
     force_new = get_force(p_list, dt, N)

     # Update particle velocity by averaging
     # current and new forces
     update_vel(p_list, 0.5*(force+force_new), dt, N)
        
    # Re-define force value
        force = force_new
        # Increase time
        time += dt
                                                                     
        print(get_pos(p_list,N))

        # Append information to data lists
        pos_list = get_pos(p_list, N)
     
        
    print(pos_list)
```

ANy help would be appreciated I've been staring at this for far too long.

EDIT: attaching get_pos; function to list down array of position. Calling get_pos gets me the array of position at time t in the range of (0, numstep).

Comment: Could you add the definition of `get_pos`?

Comment: What about `pos_list[num] = get_pos(p_list, N)`? We can only guess with so little context.

Comment: You assign to `pos_list` a 3d array, but in the loop, you assign the result of `get_pos()`, effectively throwing away the first array.  You repeat that in the loop, and end up with just the last assignment.  This isn't special `numpy` behavior, but regular Python.  That assignment in the loop **does not append**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, `pos_list` is getting overwritten by whatever the get_pos function is returning and therefor is no longer numpy array after the first iteration of the loop.

EDIT:

`pos_list = get_pos(p_list, N)` overwrites the entire `pos_list` 3D numpy array with the 2D numpy array returned by `get_pos(p_list, N)`.

To append the 2D numpy array from `get_pos` to the 3D array, at the specified index use `pos_list[num, ...] = get_pos(p_list, N)`. The returned 2D array will be recorded on the row pointed by `num` provided the 2D array is the same shape as the 3D array excluding the first column of the 3D array.